# Displaying Greek letters with subscripts inside plot

Tags: plotting

I am using ListPlot:

```
 ListPlot[dpl[[All, 1, {1, 3}]], Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> {SubsuperscriptBox["\[Xi]", "in", ""] // DisplayForm,
 "Inefficiency \[CapitalDelta]"}, 
 Joined -> True,
 PlotLabel -> {SubsuperscriptBox["\[Xi]", "out", ""] // DisplayForm} ~~
 ToString[dpl[[1, 2, 2]]]]
```

However this gives me a poor y-label: '$\{\xi_{out}\} \~\~ 7$'. How do I get this code to display '$\xi_{out}=7$'?

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Please show a *self-contained* example, explain *what you expect* and how that differs from what you get.  The `PlotLabel -> { ... // DisplayForm} ~~ ToString[...]` part of the code doesn't seem to make sense, and it's not clear to me what you are trying to achieve with `~~`, which is an operator for use with string patterns.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for `PlotLabel -> (TraditionalForm@HoldForm[Subscript[\[Xi], out] = #] &)[
  7]`.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: As well as Szabolcs  does I do not understand the question, but what I understand is that you (a) use the BoxLanguage incorrectly and (b) in the place where it is easier not to use it, but to make use of more simple tools. In particular, instead of `{SubsuperscriptBox["\[Xi]", "in", ""] // DisplayForm ` you may type `Esc+x+Esc `then `Ctrl+- `and then `in `. You will get what you need, no difficulties. Or also `PlotLabel->Style["y=7"] ` where `y=Esc+x+Esc `then `Ctrl+- `and then `out `  You did not explain what is dpl, hence I cannot help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are working too hard; i.e, using lower-level forms than you need to. Let *Mathematica* do the heavy lifting.

```
plt = Range @ 10;
ListPlot[plt,
  Frame -> True,
  FrameLabel -> {Subscript["ξ", "in"], "Inefficiency Δ"}, 
  Joined -> True,
  PlotLabel -> Row[{Subscript["ξ", "out"], "  ", plt}]]
```

[image: plot]